# PHP - join items in array based on their index

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach

I'm not sure if this question makes sense, but I have the following array:

```
Array ( 
    [columns_0_title] => qasdf 
    [columns_0_content] => zxcv 
    [columns_1_title] => Title 1 
    [columns_1_content] => content 1 
    [columns_2_title] => Title 2 
    [columns_2_content] => content 2 
    [columns_3_title] => 1 
    [columns_3_content] => 2 
    [columns_4_title] => asdf 
    [columns_4_content] => 7 
)
```

And I'd like to join the items with matching indexes.  Example, `column_0_title` & `column_0_content` would become a separate nested array

```
Array ( 
    [
        [title] => qasdf 
        [content] => zxcv 
    ]
    [
        [title] => Title 1 
        [content] => content 1 
    ]
    [
        [title] => Title 2 
        [content] => content 2 
    ]
    [
        [title] => 1 
        [content] => 2 
    ]
    [
        [title] => asdf 
        [content] => 7
    ] 
)
```

Comment: Use `explode('_', $key)` to get the parts of the original keys. Then use those as the keys of nested array elements to assign.

Comment: `$result[$parts[1]][$parts[2]] = $value`

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry but can you post a completed example, I don't completely understand.

Comment: I thought I already gave too much for a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop inside array using `foreach` and then extract index and key name  from the key using `explode` function and then add the value to new an array based on the index and key name you extracted

```
<?php
$arr = [
    "columns_0_title" => "title 0",
    "columns_0_content" => "content 0",
    "columns_1_title" => "title 1",
    "columns_1_content" => "content 1",
    "columns_2_title" => "title 2",
    "columns_2_content" => "content 2",
];
$new_arr = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $index_arr = explode("_", $key);
    $new_arr[$index_arr[1]][$index_arr[2]] = $value;
}
var_dump($new_arr);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't sure if a foreach was still needed for the explode function or not, I really appreciate the reference, this worked great